# Goal: Create a form on homepage that passes results to a landing page with a google map that filters the map based on the form input

Tags: google-maps

I want users to be able to fill out a form on my homepage. Then once they submit go to a landing page with a google map. The results from the form on the home page need to be passed to the google map and filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use POST method in your form if it contains sensitive information (like passwords...), or you can use GET method in your form if you don't mind if other users can see it...

Example:

```
<form action="landingpage.php" method="GET"> //You can use POST instead of GET
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If the user clicks the submit button, the form data will be sent to the landing page's PHP file (whose address is in the "action" parameter) via GET (or POST) for processing.

> What is the difference between POST and GET?
>   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
>
> How to redirect to another page using PHP's header function? https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp

---

Then, the landing page's php file should retrieve the submitted data via

```
'$_POST["input field's name"]'
```

or

```
'$_GET["input field's name"]'
```

---

Example for print the values:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
```

or

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
```

---

Then, you can send these to the Google Maps as options…

> How to insert Google Maps to your page?
>   https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_googlemaps.asp
>
> > More about inserting Google Maps and give parameters and options to it: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp
> >
> > (Tip: It isn't just one page, you should click "Next" button to go on…)

---

I hope I could help you.